# PDF of $X+Y$ and $X^2+Y^2$ when X, Y are independent uniform $[-1,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Using convolution:

$$
g_{X+Y}(t)=\int_\mathbb{R}g_X(t-x)g_Y(x)dx = \frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(t-x)dx =
$$

Now, $t-x \in [-1, 1] \implies -x \in [-1-t,1-t] \implies x \in [t-1, t+1]$ and we may continue ($\vee$ stands for max, $\wedge$ for min):

$$
= \frac{1}{4} \int_{-1 \vee (t-1)}^{1 \wedge t+1}dx = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 & \textrm{$t \notin [-2,2]$}\\
\frac{t+2}{4} & \textrm{$t \in (-2, 0)$}\\
\frac{-t+2}{4} & \textrm{$t \in [0, 2)$}
\end{array} \right.
$$

Is that a correct answer? I had an example of X, Y being uniform, but on $[0,1]$ and extrapolated.

How can I calculate pdf of $X^2 + Y^2$?

I already know that
$
F_{X^2}(t)=\mathbb{P}(X^2 \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(X \in [-\sqrt t, \sqrt t]) = \frac{\sqrt t - (- \sqrt t)}{1 - (-1)} = \sqrt t
$
so
$g_{X^2} = \frac{\partial F_{X^2}}{\partial t} = \frac {1}{2 \sqrt t}
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint density is given by $f(x,y)=\frac  1 4$ for $x,y \in [-1.1]$. So $P(X^{2}+Y^{2} \leq t)=\int_R f(x,y)dxdy$ where $R$ is the region defined by $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq t$. To evaluate this integral first integrate w.r.t  $x$ from $-\sqrt {t-y^{2}}$ to $\sqrt {t-y^{2}}$ to and then integrate w.r.t. $x$ from $-\sqrt t$ to $\sqrt t$. You can use the substituion $y=\sin \theta$ to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{4} \int_{- \sqrt t}^{\sqrt t}dy \int_{- \sqrt {t - y^2}}^{\sqrt{t - y^2}}dx$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.